# Laravel problem showing image in Amazon S3

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Right now I am currently having a problem trying to show the image in my Amazon S3 folder.

.env

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=somekeyid
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=somekey
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-central-1
AWS_BUCKET=https://awsq-s3.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

controller.php

```
        $tempUrl =  Storage::disk('s3')->url('randomImage.jpg');
```

This shows the url, but when I try to access/show the image, it always says: access denied.

However, this one creating file

```
        $value = Storage::disk('s3')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');
```

works and it creates the file in my bucket. I tried providing full access to my account (apply AmazonS3FullAccess policy) and it still says access denied for showing picture.

Anyone knows what is the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The uploaded image might be private. Because of it, you might not be able to display using the url. To overcome this problem, Laravel has provided the helper function `temporaryUrl($path, $expiration, array $options = [])`.

```
$expiryDate = now()->addDay(); //The link will be expire after 1 day
$temporaryUrl = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($url, $expiryDate);
```

You can now then use the $temporaryUrl to access the private files under provided expiry date.

For more information, visit the [URL documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#temporary-urls)